# Bloqueo de useState en React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formularios, react-hooks

Estoy tratando de hacer un formulario con React que te muestre una previsualización. En concreto es un formulario para crear una agenda con sus respectivos avisos.

[image: Formulario de creación de agenda]

Controlo el cambio de cada input con la siguiente función que actua sobre un useState.

```
const handleChange = (value: any, propName: any) => {
  setValueSelected({ ...valueSelected, [propName]: value });
  preview();
};
```

Tras actualizar el valor llamo a la siguiente función que primero evalúa si tiene los datos suficientes para generar la previsualización y si es asi genera el array.

```
const preview = () => {

  if (valueSelected.startTimestamp !== '' &&
    valueSelected.frequencyInterval !== '' &&
    valueSelected.repetitions !== '' &&
    valueSelected.frequency !== '') {

    let eventsList = [];

    let eventsTimestamp = moment(valueSelected.startTimestamp).valueOf();

    for (let i = 0; i < valueSelected.repetitions; i++) {
      eventsList.push({number: (i + 1 + 'º'), notificationTimestamp: eventsTimestamp});
      // @ts-ignore
      let optionFrequencySelected = optionsFrequency.find(o => o.value === valueSelected.frequency).milliseconds;
      eventsTimestamp = eventsTimestamp + (valueSelected.frequencyInterval * optionFrequencySelected);
    }

    setValueSelected({ ...valueSelected, events: eventsList });
  }
};
```

Pues bien, mi problema viene en el momento que se cumple la condición de la función preview().

Una vez se hace el `setValueSelected({ ...valueSelected, events: eventsList });` ya no se renderiza ningun cambio sobre el formulario ni sobre el array de avisos. Es como si valueSelected quedara bloqueado.

La estructura del html es la siguiente

```
<Dialog
  fullWidth
  maxWidth='md'
  open={open}
  onClose={setOpen}
>
  <AgendaContainer>

    <HeaderContainer>
      <h4>{i18n(getHeader())}</h4>
      <CloseIcon onClick={handleClose} />
    </HeaderContainer>

    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

      <BodyContainer>

        <div>

          <InputSelect
            name='activityType'
            label={i18n('user.agenda.activityType')}
            value={valueSelected.activityType.id}
            options={optionsAgenda}
            disabled={getDisabled()}
            setValueInputSelect={handleChangeActivityType}
          />

          <InputTextField
            name='observation'
            label={i18Intl('user.agenda.observation')}
            value={valueSelected.observation}
            disabled={getDisabled()}
            setValueInputText={(value: any) => handleChange(value, 'observation')}
          />

          <InputDateTime
            name='startTimestamp'
            label={i18n('user.agenda.startTimestamp')}
            value={valueSelected.startTimestamp}
            disabled={getDisabled()}
            setValueInputText={(value: any) => handleChange(value, 'startTimestamp')}
          />

          <InputTextField
            name='frequencyInterval'
            label={i18Intl('user.agenda.frequencyInterval')}
            value={valueSelected.frequencyInterval}
            type='number'
            inputProps={{
              inputProps: { min: 1 },
            }}
            disabled={getDisabled()}
            setValueInputText={(value: any) => handleChange(value, 'frequencyInterval')}
          />

          <InputSelect
            name='frequency'
            label={i18n('user.agenda.frequency')}
            value={valueSelected.frequency}
            options={optionsFrequency}
            disabled={getDisabled()}
            setValueInputSelect={handleChange}
          />

          <InputTextField
            name='repetitions'
            label={i18Intl('user.agenda.repetitions')}
            value={valueSelected.repetitions}
            type='number'
            inputProps={{
              inputProps: { min: 1 },
            }}
            disabled={getDisabled()}
            setValueInputText={(value: any) => handleChange(value, 'repetitions')}
          />

          <FormControlLabel
            label={i18n('user.agenda.toProject')}
            control={
              <Switch
                defaultChecked={valueSelected.toProject}
                onChange={handleChangeSwitch}
                disabled={getDisabled()}
                value={valueSelected.toProject}
              />
            }
          />

        </div>

        <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
          <Paper sx={{ width: '100%', overflow: 'hidden', margin: '15px' }}>

            <TableComponent
              title='user.agenda.events.title'
              dataList={valueSelected.events}
              //total={total}
              columns={columns}
              requestData={getPatientAgendaEventsAsync}
            />
          </Paper>
        </Suspense>

      </BodyContainer>

      <FooterContainer>
        <Button
          variant='outlined'
          startIcon={<CloseIcon />}
          onClick={handleClose}
        >
          {i18Intl('Close')}
        </Button>

        {(dataMode === dataModeEnum.new || dataMode === dataModeEnum.edit) &&
          <Button
            variant='contained'
            endIcon={dataMode === dataModeEnum.new ? <SaveIcon /> : <UpdateIcon />}
            onClick={handleSubmit}
          >
            {i18Intl(dataMode === dataModeEnum.new ? 'Save' : 'Update')}
          </Button>
        }
      </FooterContainer>

    </form>

  </AgendaContainer>

</Dialog>
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias!

Comment: Solo, podrias agregar el html para ver como esta estructurado, eso ayudaria, estas obteniendo informacion de la lista avisos si mal me equivoco, asi como esta estructurado la variable valueSelected

Comment: Hola @TDPerez, te agradezco tu interes, he editado el post con el html. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que al momento de hacer el primer setValueSelected() crea un conflicto con el siguiente podrias pasar los parametros que quieres cambiar al hacer el handler al preview de modo que se vea asi

```
const handleChange = (value: any, propName: any) => {
  preview(value , propName);
};
```

y para preview

```
const preview = (value: any, propName: any) =>{
    ...
    setValueSelected({ ...valueSelected, events: eventsList, [propName]: value });
}
```

incluso aqui podrias solo hacer un handler, asi se evita ese problema que el estado no se este cambiando correctamente al volver a llamar el otro estado, revisa tambien que esta mandando value, porque si es un input puede que salga de la siguiente forma

```
{
    target:{
        name:'name',
        value:'value',
    }
}
```

Que tambien puede ser el caso de que no envie nada

Comment: Efectivamente parece que entraban en conflicto, he dejado todo en el handleChange. Si cumple la condicion seteo ambos valores a la vez

`setValueSelected({ ...valueSelected, events: eventsList, [propName]: value });`

Y si no solo el que ha sido modificado.

Comment: El único problema con esta solución es que la lista de avisos se actualiza con el valor anterior del input que modificas, por eso mi idea inicial de tenerlo separado.

Answer (score 0):

Este ha sido el resultado final

```
const handleChange = (value: any, propName: any) => {

  let start = propName === 'startTimestamp' ? value : valueSelected.startTimestamp;
  let rep = propName === 'repetitions' ? value : valueSelected.repetitions;
  let freq = propName === 'frequency' ? value : valueSelected.frequency;
  let freqInt = propName === 'frequencyInterval' ? value : valueSelected.frequencyInterval;

  if (start !== '' && freqInt !== '' && rep !== '' && freq !== '') {

    let eventsList = [];

    let eventsTimestamp = moment(start).valueOf();

    for (let i = 0; i < rep; i++) {
      eventsList.push({ number: (i + 1 + 'º'), notificationTimestamp: eventsTimestamp });

      // @ts-ignore
      let optionFrequencySelected = optionsFrequency.find(o => o.value === freq).milliseconds;

      eventsTimestamp = eventsTimestamp + (freqInt * optionFrequencySelected);
    }

    setValueSelected({ ...valueSelected, events: eventsList, [propName]: value });
  } else {
    setValueSelected({ ...valueSelected, [propName]: value });
  }
};
```

Comment: Aqui puedes asignar valueSelect a una variable como val, entonces podes val[propName] = value, y en los eventos seria val.events = eventsList para luego hacer el setValueSelect(val), con eso podrias ahorar esa comprovacion